# awk: reading filename, column separator and fields to omit from an input file

Tags: variables, awk

I have an input file called t.txt with a list of filenames, column separator and fields to omit separated by ':'

```
file1:~:$1$2$3
file2:;:$21
```

Like to read this file from a ksh script and use the fields as variable to execute awk

something like the following but I am getting error. Any idea how to do it correctly?

```
while IFS=":" read -r filename separator ignore_cols
do
   awk -v sep="$seperator" -v icols="$ignore_cols" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=sep} {icols=""; print $0}' $filename > $filenames.cols_removed
done < t.txt
```

Comment: We won't know about the error unless you post here.

Comment: Error:   Awk: syntax error near line 1   awk: bailng out near line 1

Comment: have you verified that `awk '{$1$2$3=""}'` actually works?  I'm guessing this is what your error refers to but ... it would help if you updated the question with the complete error message (which typically has a pointer to the location in the `awk` command where the error is occurring)

Comment: it is actually file1:~:$1=$2=$3.   these are all the errors that I am getting

Comment: I basically want to read the filename, sep and cols to ignore from a file. If anyone has a solution I appreciate it

Comment: One obvious issue is that you have separator misspelt in awk ; that could be one issue you are encountering.

Comment: That error message looks like an "old" awk error message. Try `nawk` or `gawk` on your system. You may get a much better error message. Please get in the habit of including relevant information in the body of your Q and DON'T reply to such requests in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ cat file1 <(echo "===") file2 <(echo "===") t.txt
A~B~C~D~E~F~G~H~I
1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9
===
A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9
===
/tmp/file1:~:$1$2$3
/tmp/file2:;:$3
```

You can do something like this:

```
while IFS=":" read -r filename sep ignore
do
    awk -v sep="$sep" -v icols="$ignore" '
        BEGIN {FS=OFS=sep
            split(icols, a, /\$/)
            for (e in a) ign[a[e]]
        } 
    {   s="";c=0
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if (i in ign) continue
        s= (c++ ? s OFS : "") $i;
        }
        print s
    } ' "$filename" 
done < t.txt
```

Prints:

```
D~E~F~G~H~I
4~5~6~7~8~9
A;B;D;E;F;G;H;I
1;2;4;5;6;7;8;9
```

Which can be redirected to a new file as you had before.

**Don't forget to quote properly in the shell!** (You did not "quote" `$filename` or the output `$filenames.cols_removed`...)

Comment: pluse-uno for sainthood ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@shelter is correct in that you're using the default awk on Solaris aka old, broken awk. Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (or xpg6) instead. To do what you're trying to do though would just be 1 call to awk (untested):

```
awk -F';' '
NR==FNR {
    ARGV[ARGC] = $1
    fss[ARGC] = $2
    fieldLists[ARGC] = $3
    ARGC++
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME ".cols_removed"
    ++fileCnt
    FS = OFS = fss[fileCnt]
    $0 = $0
    split(fieldLists[fileCnt],tmp,/\$/)
    for (i in tmp) {
        skip[tmp[i]]
    }
    nf = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( !(i in skip) ) {
            f[++nf] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS) > out
    }
}
' t.txt
```

Comment: ah yes, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, even better!  ++ for more sainthood demonstrated by the awk-squad ;-)!

Comment: @shellter yeah xpg4 is closer to POSIX-compliant than nawk, e.g. it supports character classes, so fewer surprises.

Comment: @sid : One more thing, as it seems you **are** using a Unix system (Sun?), best to mention that in any questions you post, as the default assumption now-a-days is that Linux and GNU tools are being used. Also if the posted answers here helped solve your problem, feel free to up-vote them and if one specifically was best and solved your problem, you can accept that answer, which give reputation points to the people that take time to help you. Good luck to all.